# how to use command line arguments with python manage.py

Tags: python, django

I get an error when I run the command shown in the image below

[image]

```
python manage.py shell <processing.py 66
```

error is

```
usage: manage.py shell [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS]
                   [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color]
                   [--plain] [--no-startup] [-i {ipython,bpython,python}]
                   [-c COMMAND]
```

i think its not the right way to pass arguments while using shell.
   i cannot directly write

```
python processing.py
```

because i am using database filtering and so i have to use shell.

this is my processing.py

```
import os
import sys
from webapp.models import status


dirname = sys.argv[1]

print(os.getcwd())
sta = status.objects.filter(status_id=66)[0]
sta.status = True
sta.save()
print(sta.status)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to write a custom django-admin command. have a look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want to create a custom management command, as mentioned in comments. Here's an example of one, which will print a passed command line argument, which should be placed in an app in a location like `myapp/management/commands/say.py` and called with `python manage.py say --printme StackOverFlow`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    """
    This command will print a command line argument.
    """
    help = 'This command will import locations from a CSV file into the hivapp Locations model.'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '--printme',
            action='store',
            dest='printme',
            default="Hello world!",
            help='''The string to print.'''
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print(options['printme'])
```

You could pass a file name to iterate over with a list of command to run, although incorporate the commands into your command would be safer. Good luck!